# Rails root url returns blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i'm trying to get *`mydomain.com`* it returns blank page with no errors.

I have the correct root in `routes.rb` and when I'm trying to get the page that must be root *`mydomain.com/root_page`* it works fine.

Any page of my site works fine
*`public/index.html`* is deleted.

what is the problem with this approach?

Thanks.

here is my routes.rb file

```
    mydomain.com::Application.routes.draw do

  get "admin/index"
  match "admin" => "admin#index"

  match "materialy" => "materials#indexall"
  match "materialy/:id" => "materials#showall"
  match "m/:id" => "materials#light"

  match "nashi-raboti" => "ourworks#indexall"
  match "nashi-raboti/:alias" => "wphotos#indexall"

  match "galereja" => "gphotos#indexall"

  scope "/admin" do
    resources :gphotos, :materials, :posts, :mphotos, :titles
    resources :ourworks do 
      resources :wphotos
    end
  end

  match ":alias" => "posts#showall"

  root :to => "posts#showall", :alias => "main"

end
```

so when im trying to get mydomain.com/main everything works fine.

Nothing is written to development.log when i'm truing to get mydomain.com, but everything is good when i'm trying to get mydomain.com/main or any other page.

Comment: ... Without knowing anything about your routes, controller, views, etc. I'm not sure how anybody could help.

Comment: ^ He's right. Post logs, too.

Comment: As is, your question is too vague to receive a meaningful or helpful response. Consider expanding your question to include a more detailed description of your rails configuration posting the contents of whichever log or configuration files might be at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mydomain.com" it is your application name? I think the problem is due to this. Try create app without dot in name.

Comment: no no, it's not my application name, i just tried to hide real application name

Comment: ок, и я только что проверил, что рельсы не дадут создать приложение с точкой в имени :-)